# What is the format of the content in the .text generated by the linker?

Tags: compilation, linker

During the compilation process, the linker maps our code text content into the .text in the code memory section. I would like to know what is the meaning of the text content, does it mean the actual code in text or in assembly?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it mean the actual code in text or in assembly?

Neither: it's actual code in machine instructions.

For example:

```
$ cat > t.c
int foo() { return 42; }
$ gcc -c t.c
$ objdump -d t.o

t.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   b8 2a 00 00 00          mov    $0x2a,%eax
   9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   a:   c3                      retq
```

The contents of the `.text` section is the following 11 bytes:

```
554889e5b82a0000005dc3
```

**Update:**

> is it correct to say that it contains the assembly code which converted into machine readable binary format?

You could say that, but it not very clear.

Perhaps "contains machine readable binary instructions, produced by compiling and assembling the program source, and applying relocations". (That last part is what the linker does, not demonstrated in the example above.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. So is it correct to say that it contains the assembly code which converted into machine readable binary format?